# swift class as parameter without .self

Tags: ios, swift

I've wrote some functions (Swift 2.1, XCode 7.1.1):

```
public func test1<T:UIView>(type: T.Type) -> T {
    print(type.dynamicType)
    return type.init()
}

public func test2<T:UIView>(type: T.Type)(_ n: Int) -> T {
    print(type.dynamicType)
    return type.init()
}

public func test3<T1:UIView, T2:UIView>(type1: T1.Type, _ type2: T2.Type) {
    print(type1.init())
    print(type2.init())
}

public func test4<T:UIView>(type: T.Type, _ n: Int) {
    print(type.init())
    print(n)
}

public func test5<T:UIView>(n: Int,_ type: T.Type) {
    print(type.init())
    print(n)
}
```

And call them with:

```
test1(UIButton)
test1(UIButton.self)

test2(UIButton)(1)
test2(UIButton.self)(1)

test3(UIButton.self, UITextField.self)

test4(UIButton.self, 1)

test5(1, UIButton.self)
```

As you can see, when a type is the only parameter, it can omit the ".self". But for all functions that not have only a type parameter, they require the ".self".

I want to know:

1. Why is That?
2. And how to declare a function with multiple parameters that doesn't need ".self" where using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally, this just came up on swift-evolution. The ability to omit `.self` when the Type is the only argument, has been reported as a [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-899) in Swift.

The relevant quote from Apple:

> It's a bug. `.self` is supposed to be required everywhere.
>   Unfortunately, we've had the bug for a while, so I'm not sure how much
>   code we'd break by changing it. If we wanted to remove the
>   requirement, that would be considered a language change and would have
>   to go through the Swift Evolution Process.

Comment: Oh, why that's a bug? I'd like it to be a feature. The reason I am asking this is I want create a DSL take class as parameter, something like layout(UIVIew, [ViewClass1, ViewClass2, ..]). It's not very elegant with .self all over the place.