# Swift 2.2 - Using initialiser with variadic parameters of class type

Tags: swift, initialization, variadic

In Swift 2.2, I have the following classes:

```
protocol Base {}

class FirstImpl: Base {}

class SecondImpl: Base {}

class Container {
    private var typeNames = Set<String>()

    init(_ types: Base.Type...) {
       for type in types {
           typeNames.insert(String(type))
       }
    }
}
```

If I only add a single class type to the Container, then it compiles fine:

```
let c = Container(FirstImpl)
```

But if I start adding more class types, then it will not compile:

```
let c = Container(FirstImpl, SecondImpl)
```

The build error is:

*Cannot convert value of type '(FirstImpl, SecondImpl).Type' to expected argument type 'Base.Type'*

Is it a limitation in the Swift compiler or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a confusing error message, but the problem is that you need to use `.self` in order to [refer to the types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455) of your classes when passing them into a function. Therefore you'll want to do:

```
let c = Container(FirstImpl.self, SecondImpl.self)
```

Your first example that compiles without `.self` is in fact [a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-899) (which has been resolved as of Swift 3) – see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869950/swift-class-as-parameter-without-self) for more info.